# Call a method from A class in constructor of other class

Tags: c++

I want to call a method from A class in constructor of other class

I googled, but did not find any answer
For example, I have :

```
class A{
  void doWork();
}
class B{
  B(){
   //here i want to have doWork method
 }
}
```

Comment: Does `B` have a pointer or reference to an instance of `A`?  Is `doWork()` static?  Is `B` a subclass of `A`?  Otherwise, you can't call a method from another class, constructor or otherwise

Comment: You can call a method (non-member, static member functions or if you have an instance of `A` a member function) from within the constructor of `B`, however there is no "calling from method **into** a constructor", that doesn't make sense...

Comment: Care to comment on the downvotes? The question is not of the best quality, but it's quite clear, what are intentions of the OP. And beginner's questions are as welcome on the SO as pro's ones, isn't it?

Comment: Voting to keep this open, As Spook points out it could be worded better but it's relatively straight forward question with perhaps an answer pointing towards using inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told us not enough to choose proper solution. Everything depends on what you are trying to achieve. A few solutions:

a) Mark A method as static.

```
class A
{
public:
    static void DoSth()
    {
        // Cannot access non-static A members here!
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A::DoSth();
    }
};
```

b) You can instantiate A in place

```
class A
{
public:
    void DoSth()
    {
        // Do something
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A a;
        a.DoSth();
    }
};
```

c) You can put A's instance into B:

```
// A remains as in b)

class B
{
private:
    A a;
    // or: A * a;

public:
    B()
    {
        a.DoSth();
        // or: a = new A; a->DoSth();
        // Remember to free a somewhere
        // (probably in destructor)
    }
}
```

d) You may derive B from A:

```
class A
{
protected:
    void DoSth()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        DoSth();
    }
};
```

e) You can forget about A class and make DoSth a function:

```
void DoSth()
{
    // ...
}

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        DoSth();
    }
}
```

Since you provided not enough data, you have to choose solution on your own.

Answer (score 3):

In order for that to work you'd need to subclass it.

So it'd be like this:

```
class A {
  doWork();
}

class B : A {
   B(){
     doWork();
   }
}
```

You could also do it like so going for a HAS-A rather than IS-A relationship:

```
class A {
   doWork();
}

class B {
   A myA;
   B(){
      myA.doWork();
   }
}
```

Without knowing more of what you are doing I'd go with the top (IS-A) solution which is what I think you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
class A
{
    public:
         static void doWork();
};
class B
{
     B(void)
     {
          A::doWork();
     }
};
```

?

PS: Here B::B() will be private